# How can I return a single value from an SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I forget to return  value in single tier application.

```
public  int Studentid()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT s_id FROM student where name = + ('" + Request.QueryString.ToString() + "')", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                //Want help hear how I return value
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx)

Comment: I want to rturn s_id if student name is `Request.QueryString.ToString.`Thats all.Thanks.

Comment: Is no one going to show @ShreeKhanal how to avoid the SQL injection vulnerability?

Comment: @qes: Good point. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a version of your method that achieves what you're after.

```
public int GetStudentId()
{
    var sql = string.Format("SELECT s_id FROM student where name = '{0}'", Request.QueryString);
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return dr.Read() ? return dr.GetInt32(0) : -1;
    }
}
```

There's no need to use try/catch when you don't do anything with the exception except re-throw (and in fact you were losing the original stack trace by using `throw ex;` instead of just `throw;`.  Also, the C# `using` statement takes care of cleaning up your resources for you in fewer lines of code.

***IMPORTANT***

Passing the query string directly into SQL like that means that anyone can execute random SQL into your database, potentially deleting everything (or worse).  Read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Is it OK we don't close the SqlConnection ?

Comment: @JuliusPrayogo it's not the end of the world, but you should close it. If you don't the GC will close it at some later point, but this can cause problems such as running out of connection objects. I can't think of a good reason not to close it, can you?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `using` blocks, so that you are sure that the connection, command and reader are closed correctly. Then you can just return the value from inside the `if` statement, and doesn't have to store it in a variable until you have closed the objects.

You only have to open the connection once.

You should use parameterised queries, instead of concatenating values into the query.

```
public  int Studentid() {
  try {
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr)) {
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT s_id FROM student where name = @Name", con)) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", DbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Request.QueryString.ToString();
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
          if (dr.Read()) {
            return dr.GetInt32(0);
          } else {
            return -1; // some value to indicate a missing record
            // or throw an exception
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    throw; // just as this, to rethrow with the stack trace intact
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to return a single value is to call `ExecuteScalar`. You should also fix your SQL injection bug. And did you mean to encode the entire query string array, or just to pick out a single value?

```
public int StudentId()
{
    string sql = "SELECT s_id FROM student WHERE name = @name";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", DbType.VarChar, 256).Value = Request.QueryString["name"];
            con.Open();
            return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
int s_id = (int) dr["s_id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int studId=0;
if(rdr.Read())
{
  studId=rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("s_id"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (dr.Read())
            {
                //Want help hear how i return value
                int value = dr.GetInt32("s_id");
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```
public  int Studentid()
{
        int studentId = -1;
        SqlConnection con = null;
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT s_id FROM student where name = + ('" + Request.QueryString.ToString() + "')", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                studentId = dr.GetInt32(0);
            }

            dr.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(con != null)
                 con.Close();
            con = null;
        }

       return studentId;
 }
```

Comment: I know you just copied then modified his code, but -1 for duplicating all his bugs in the process.