# How to return and retrieve object value in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using 3 layer architecture for my project. But for an instance i need to return Object from a method and retrieve the values.
Here are my two Models:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Product Products { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

and my method is:

```
public class ProductGateway{

public List<Product> GetProductByProductId(int productId)
    {
        List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        string query = "SELECT ProductName,cast(Price as decimal(10,2)) as Price FROM   Product  WHERE ProductId='" + productId + "' ";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {              
            Product product = new Product(); 
            product.ProductName = reader["ProductName"].ToString();
            product.Price = (decimal)reader["Price"];
            productList.Add(product);
        }
        return productList;
}
    }
```

and my Controller:**CartController**

```
ProductGateway gateway=new ProductGateway();
public ActionResult BuyProduct( int id)
    {
        if (Session["cart"]==null)
        {
            List<Item> cart= new List<Item>();
            cart.Add(new Item()
            {
                Products = gateway.GetProductByProductId(id),// this line getting an error(no list)
                Quantity = 1
            });
            Session["cart"] = cart;
        }
```

And my cshtml view:

```
@{
                    var cart = (List<Item>) Session["cart"];
                }
                @foreach (var item in cart)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cart_product">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Product", new { id = item.Products.ProductId })">@item.Product.Price </a>// an error occurred on ProductId and Price
```

Now problem is that my return type is List the Controller get an error on`Products = gateway.AllProductsByProductId(id)` and ask for change Item model as `Public List<Product> Products` .Thus I want to send Object from GetProductByProductId to avoid error in Cart Controller. Is there any way to solve this issue or i need to change entire codes? I really get confused with this scenario.

**My Requirement**

**1.I need to use product property such as `@item.Product.Price` in my cshtml view. (Current Error: Cannot resolve symbol `Price`)**

**2.So that my gateway should return an Product object rather than list of Porduct(for now gateway return list of products).**

**3. If it is possible to return Object from gateway(assume gateway return single product for each id) then how could I retrieve that object from Cart Controller**

Thanks

Comment: what is `AllProductsByProductId`? You have shown another method but then you are calling this method.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Edited

Comment: Why are you returning  a `List` from `GetProductByProductId(int productId)`? Do you have multiple products with the same `productId`? I doubt this is the case. Therefore, return one product and then you can use the one product in your view.

Comment: I want do so. that reason I want set return type 'Product' from 'List<Product>' as it return only single product. But I don't know how could I send single Product from the gateway. @CodingYoshi

Comment: The easiest solution is to do this in your gateway: `return productList.First()` and change the signature of the method to return `Product` not `List<Product>`. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702386/how-can-i-return-a-single-value-from-an-sqldatareader) for a better way.

Comment: @CodingYoshi thanks you very much. I spent almost two days for this. And its really hard to make anyone understand what I really  want. Thanks once again. You saved my life.

Comment: I added an answer so others know your question has been answered. I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comments you indicated that only a single product can exist with a give product Id. In that case, your `GetProductByProductId(int productId)` should return one product. Make the following changes to the method:

```
public Product GetProductByProductId(int productId)
{
    // your code

    // Change this part
    if(reader.Read())
    {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.ProductName = reader["ProductName"].ToString();
        product.Price = (decimal)reader["Price"];
        return product;
    }

    // not found so we can return null or whatever you want
    return null;
}
```

And you should also try using `SqlParameter` to avoid [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) especially if the parameter is coming from an end user.

Comment: Thanks you very much and I will keep it mind about SQl Injection.@CodingYoshi